# Programmatically disable action center

Tags: windows-7

I'm looking for a way to programmatically disable the action center. Is this even possible? I want to have a one click way to do this in order to run this remotely if I need to.

So far I have thought of disabling the Security Center service but I don't really want to lose automatic windows updates. Maybe there is some way do disable security center service while enabling windows update?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using a Pro+ version of Windows 7 you can use Group Policy to control how the Action Center acts.

Specifically the `User Configuration\Administrative Templates\Start Menu and Taskbar\Remove the Action Center icon` policy:

> If you enable this policy setting, you remove the Action Center icon
>   from the notification area. This also means that Action Center will
>   not display any balloon notifications.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't even think about group policy!